# RedShift - Database Access Management

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, roles

When I am creating a user in RedShift from a superuser account, the user created has full access(select, insert, update, delete, drop, references) to all DBs in the cluster and all schemas on the DBs.

When I am using REVOKE to limit access, the access for the user does not change.

How can I create a user in RedShift with limited access to databases and schemas? Commands from the documentation execute but do not change access level.

Comment: What CREATE USER command options are you using?  Are you providing the CREATEUSER option?

Comment: Yes. Tried below: create group readonlyusers;

create group developmentusers;

create user <> password ''
in group readonlyusers;

create user <> password ''
in group developmentusers;

Comment: Also tried CREATE USER username_dev
  WITH PASSWORD 'md5';
  
  select md5('' || 'username_dev');
  GRANT ALL ON DATABASE dev TO username_dev
  REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA test FROM username_dev

Comment: Both users get default access to all databases in the clusters.

Comment: 'Yes', you are using the CREATEUSER option to CREATE USER???  I don't see this option in your queries.   Can you post the contents of pg_users for this user?